# get result from more than one sql as column wise

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have different sql which returns different result.And I need to get all them as column wise. But I have no idea how to do it.Can anyone please help me on this please? here is my sql below >>>

```
    SELECT  "one" AS value_1,
    "two" AS value_2

SELECT  "three" AS value_3,
    "four" AS value_4

SELECT  "five" AS value_5,
    "six" AS value_6
```

main query 1>>>

```
    SELECT -- lat.`group_info_id`, gi.`group_name`, 
    SUM(lat.`principal_outstanding`) AS principalOutstanding -- , SUM(lat.`accrued_interest`) AS interestReceivable, SUM(lat.`realizable_interest`) AS interestRealizable
    -- , SUM(lat.`principal_outstanding`)+SUM(lat.`accrued_interest`)+SUM(lat.`realizable_interest`) AS loanDue, SUM(lat.`outstanding_balance`) AS totalLoanDue
FROM loan_account_transaction AS lat
INNER JOIN loan_account AS la ON (la.id = lat.`loan_account_id`)
LEFT JOIN group_info AS gi ON (gi.id = lat.`group_info_id`)
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT MAX(ilat.id) AS max_lat_id, ilat.loan_account_id 
FROM loan_account_transaction AS ilat
WHERE ilat.`domain_status_id` = 1 AND ilat.`office_info_id` = (SELECT id FROM office_info WHERE office_code = 'UG500002')
AND ilat.`project_info_id` IN ('BI0000000000000000000004') AND ilat.transaction_date <= '2013-04-30'
GROUP BY ilat.loan_account_id
) AS tlat ON (tlat.loan_account_id = lat.`loan_account_id` AND tlat.max_lat_id = lat.id)
WHERE lat.`office_info_id` = (SELECT id FROM office_info WHERE office_code = 'UG500002') 
AND lat.`project_info_id` IN ('BI0000000000000000000004') 
AND lat.`loan_status_id` != 2 AND lat.`loan_status_id` != 7 AND la.`domain_status_id` = 1 AND lat.`domain_status_id` = 1
```

main query 2 >>>

```
 SELECT     SUM(CASE WHEN la.loan_duration = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_count_40,
    SUM(CASE WHEN la.loan_duration = 12 THEN IFNULL(la.disbursed_amount,0) ELSE 0 END) AS disbursed_amount_40,
    SUM(CASE WHEN la.loan_duration = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_count_20,
    SUM(CASE WHEN la.loan_duration = 6 THEN IFNULL(la.disbursed_amount,0) ELSE 0 END) AS disbursed_amount_20
FROM    loan_account AS la
INNER JOIN member_info AS mi ON (la.disbursement_date <='2013-04-30'
    AND la.project_info_id IN ('BI0000000000000000000004')
    AND la.domain_status_id = 1 AND la.member_id=mi.id )
INNER JOIN office_info AS oi
 ON( oi.id = 'BI0000000000000000000363' AND mi.branch_info_id = oi.id )
```

** new one >>>

```
    SELECT  COUNT(1), SUM(principal_outstanding) 
FROM
(

/* Current Loan */
        SELECT  tempData.country_id,
         tempData.project_info_id,
        tempData.prodId,
        tempData.loan_name,
       tempData.office_info_id,
        office_info.office_code,
        office_info.office_name,
        tempData.group_info_id,
        group_info.group_code,
        group_info.group_name,
        missed_days,
        SUM(tempData.principal_outstanding) AS principal_outstanding,
        COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) AS borrower_count

        FROM (
                SELECT lat.country_id,lat.office_info_id,lat.project_info_id, lp.id AS prodId, lp.`loan_name`,
                lat.group_info_id,
                lat.principal_outstanding,la.member_id,

                (CEIL(lat.overdue_amount/la.installment_amount) *
                        CASE WHEN lpp.policy_repayments_plan_id = 1 THEN
                            1
                        WHEN lpp.policy_repayments_plan_id = 2 THEN
                            7
                        WHEN lpp.policy_repayments_plan_id = 3 THEN
                            30
                        WHEN lpp.policy_repayments_plan_id = 4 THEN
                            365
                        END) AS missed_days
                FROM loan_account_transaction AS lat
                INNER JOIN loan_account AS la ON (la.id = lat.loan_account_id)
                INNER JOIN loan_product AS lp ON (la.`product_info_id` = lp.`id`)
                INNER JOIN loan_product_policy AS lpp ON(lpp.id = la.policy_info_id)
                INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(lat2.id) AS max_lat2_id,lat2.loan_account_id FROM loan_account_transaction AS lat2
                WHERE lat2.transaction_date <=   '2013-03-31'   AND
                lat2.domain_status_id = 1 AND
                 lat2.country_id IN (1) AND 
                 lat2.office_info_id IN ('BI0000000000000000000363') AND 
                 lat2.project_info_id IN ('BI0000000000000000000004') 
                GROUP BY lat2.loan_account_id
            ) AS temp ON lat.id = temp.max_lat2_id
            WHERE (lat.loan_status_id= 1  OR lat.loan_status_id IS NULL)
        ) AS tempData
        INNER JOIN office_info ON (office_info.id = tempData.office_info_id)
        LEFT JOIN group_info ON (group_info.id = tempData.group_info_id)
        WHERE missed_days > 30
        GROUP BY
        tempData.country_id,
        tempData.office_info_id,
        tempData.project_info_id,
        tempData.prodId,
        tempData.group_info_id,
        missed_days

UNION

/* Late and NIBL Loan */
        SELECT  tempData.country_id,tempData.project_info_id,
                tempData.prodId,
        tempData.loan_name,
                tempData.office_info_id,office_info.office_code,office_info.office_name,
                tempData.group_info_id,group_info.group_code,group_info.group_name,
                tempData.missed_days,SUM(tempData.principal_outstanding) AS principal_outstanding,
                COUNT(DISTINCT tempData.member_id) AS borrower_count
        FROM
        (SELECT lat.country_id,lat.office_info_id,lat.project_info_id, lp.id AS prodId, lp.`loan_name`,
                lat.group_info_id,
                    (CASE WHEN lat.loan_status_id = 3 THEN
                        (la.loan_duration*30) -- +(la.loan_duration*30/2)
                    WHEN lat.loan_status_id = 4 THEN
                        (la.loan_duration*30) -- *2
                    WHEN lat.loan_status_id = 5 THEN
                        (la.loan_duration*30) -- *2+7
                    WHEN lat.loan_status_id = 6 THEN
                        (la.loan_duration*30) -- *2+7
                    END) AS missed_days,
                lat.principal_outstanding,la.member_id
                FROM loan_account_transaction AS lat
                INNER JOIN loan_account AS la ON (la.id = lat.loan_account_id)
                INNER JOIN loan_product AS lp ON (la.`product_info_id` = lp.`id`)
                INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(lat2.id) AS max_lat2_id,lat2.loan_account_id FROM
                loan_account_transaction AS lat2
                WHERE lat2.transaction_date <=   '2013-03-31'   AND
                lat2.domain_status_id = 1 AND
                 lat2.country_id IN (1) AND 
                 lat2.office_info_id IN ('BI0000000000000000000363') AND 
                 lat2.project_info_id IN ('BI0000000000000000000004') 
                GROUP BY lat2.loan_account_id
            ) AS temp ON lat.id = temp.max_lat2_id
                WHERE (lat.loan_status_id != 2 AND lat.loan_status_id != 7 AND lat.loan_status_id = 1)
        ) AS tempData
        INNER JOIN office_info ON (office_info.id = tempData.office_info_id)
        LEFT JOIN group_info ON (group_info.id = tempData.group_info_id)
        GROUP BY tempData.country_id,
        tempData.office_info_id,
        tempData.project_info_id,
        tempData.prodId,
        tempData.group_info_id,
        missed_days

        ) AS t
        GROUP BY t.prodId
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL server or both? Also, could you add a desired result where the 3 queries give different number of results?

Comment: What is column wise???

Comment: Get them row wise and use a programming language to do a matrix transpose. (lazy solution)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You posted three separate "queries" (they're not real queries) and no definition of what "column wise" is supposed to mean. With those three separate statements, what output would you like to get? And MySQL and SQL Server are two totally separate DBMSs (they're not the same at all), so which one are you asking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yu can use the below query,

```
select * from
    (
        (SELECT  'one' AS value_1, 'two' AS value_2) A

    JOIN (SELECT  'three' AS value_3, 'four' AS value_4) B  ON 1=1

    JOIN (SELECT  'five' AS value_5, 'six' AS value_6) C  ON 1=1
    )
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ede9b/1/0)

**ANSWER FOR THE NEW QUESTION :**

I'm not sure f this is going to work. But just try it.

```
SELECT * from
 (SELECT  COUNT(1) COUNT1, SUM(principal_outstanding) SUM1
FROM
(

/* Current Loan */
        SELECT  tempData.country_id,
         tempData.project_info_id,
        tempData.prodId,
        tempData.loan_name,
       tempData.office_info_id,
        office_info.office_code,
        office_info.office_name,
        tempData.group_info_id,
        group_info.group_code,
        group_info.group_name,
        missed_days,
        SUM(tempData.principal_outstanding) AS principal_outstanding,
        COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) AS borrower_count

        FROM (
                SELECT lat.country_id,lat.office_info_id,lat.project_info_id, lp.id AS prodId, lp.`loan_name`,
                lat.group_info_id,
                lat.principal_outstanding,la.member_id,

                (CEIL(lat.overdue_amount/la.installment_amount) *
                        CASE WHEN lpp.policy_repayments_plan_id = 1 THEN
                            1
                        WHEN lpp.policy_repayments_plan_id = 2 THEN
                            7
                        WHEN lpp.policy_repayments_plan_id = 3 THEN
                            30
                        WHEN lpp.policy_repayments_plan_id = 4 THEN
                            365
                        END) AS missed_days
                FROM loan_account_transaction AS lat
                INNER JOIN loan_account AS la ON (la.id = lat.loan_account_id)
                INNER JOIN loan_product AS lp ON (la.`product_info_id` = lp.`id`)
                INNER JOIN loan_product_policy AS lpp ON(lpp.id = la.policy_info_id)
                INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(lat2.id) AS max_lat2_id,lat2.loan_account_id FROM loan_account_transaction AS lat2
                WHERE lat2.transaction_date <=   '2013-03-31'   AND
                lat2.domain_status_id = 1 AND
                 lat2.country_id IN (1) AND 
                 lat2.office_info_id IN ('BI0000000000000000000363') AND 
                 lat2.project_info_id IN ('BI0000000000000000000004') 
                GROUP BY lat2.loan_account_id
            ) AS temp ON lat.id = temp.max_lat2_id
            WHERE (lat.loan_status_id= 1  OR lat.loan_status_id IS NULL)
        ) AS tempData
        INNER JOIN office_info ON (office_info.id = tempData.office_info_id)
        LEFT JOIN group_info ON (group_info.id = tempData.group_info_id)
        WHERE missed_days > 30
        GROUP BY
        tempData.country_id,
        tempData.office_info_id,
        tempData.project_info_id,
        tempData.prodId,
        tempData.group_info_id,
        missed_days ) g1
        GROUP BY g1.prodId )t1



/* Late and NIBL Loan */
       JOIN (SELECT  COUNT(1) COUNT2, SUM(principal_outstanding) SUM2
FROM(SELECT  tempData.country_id,tempData.project_info_id,
                tempData.prodId,
        tempData.loan_name,
                tempData.office_info_id,office_info.office_code,office_info.office_name,
                tempData.group_info_id,group_info.group_code,group_info.group_name,
                tempData.missed_days,SUM(tempData.principal_outstanding) AS principal_outstanding,
                COUNT(DISTINCT tempData.member_id) AS borrower_count
        FROM
        (SELECT lat.country_id,lat.office_info_id,lat.project_info_id, lp.id AS prodId, lp.`loan_name`,
                lat.group_info_id,
                    (CASE WHEN lat.loan_status_id = 3 THEN
                        (la.loan_duration*30) -- +(la.loan_duration*30/2)
                    WHEN lat.loan_status_id = 4 THEN
                        (la.loan_duration*30) -- *2
                    WHEN lat.loan_status_id = 5 THEN
                        (la.loan_duration*30) -- *2+7
                    WHEN lat.loan_status_id = 6 THEN
                        (la.loan_duration*30) -- *2+7
                    END) AS missed_days,
                lat.principal_outstanding,la.member_id
                FROM loan_account_transaction AS lat
                INNER JOIN loan_account AS la ON (la.id = lat.loan_account_id)
                INNER JOIN loan_product AS lp ON (la.`product_info_id` = lp.`id`)
                INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(lat2.id) AS max_lat2_id,lat2.loan_account_id FROM
                loan_account_transaction AS lat2
                WHERE lat2.transaction_date <=   '2013-03-31'   AND
                lat2.domain_status_id = 1 AND
                 lat2.country_id IN (1) AND 
                 lat2.office_info_id IN ('BI0000000000000000000363') AND 
                 lat2.project_info_id IN ('BI0000000000000000000004') 
                GROUP BY lat2.loan_account_id
            ) AS temp ON lat.id = temp.max_lat2_id
                WHERE (lat.loan_status_id != 2 AND lat.loan_status_id != 7 AND lat.loan_status_id = 1)
        ) AS tempData
        INNER JOIN office_info ON (office_info.id = tempData.office_info_id)
        LEFT JOIN group_info ON (group_info.id = tempData.group_info_id)
        GROUP BY tempData.country_id,
        tempData.office_info_id,
        tempData.project_info_id,
        tempData.prodId,
        tempData.group_info_id,
        missed_days

        ) AS g2
        GROUP BY g2.prodId) t2 ON 1=1
```

Comment: it works. thanks. Can you help me a little more please. I have a sql that returns result in two rows and two fields. But I want the result in one row and in four fields. I am uploading the query as new one. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: thanks for your try. It returns 4 column as expected. But no value

Answer (score 0):

Might this be what you mean?

```
SELECT id, column1 AS data
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT id, column2 AS data
FROM table2
UNION
SELECT id, column3 AS data
FROM table3;
```

The columns `column1`, `column2`, `column3` should all have the same data type, and aliasing them to have the same name is what lets the `UNION`s work.

Comment: thanks for reply. But if I use union I don't get the appropriate column name in result. I am giving my original query. It is big. that's why I posted like this. All I need is that I want the each queary result as a column. that's all.

Answer (score 0):

```
      
 WITH    cte ( value1, value2 )
                      AS ( SELECT   'ONE' AS value_1 ,
                                    'TWO' AS value_2
                         ),
                    cte2
                      AS ( SELECT   'THREE' AS value_3 ,
                                    'FOUR' AS value_4
                         ),
                    cte3
                      AS ( SELECT   'FIVE' AS value_5 ,
                                    'SIX' AS value_6
                         )
                SELECT  *
                FROM    cte ,
                        cte2 ,
                        cte3
```

Comment: I think you are looking for this.